# Can I use std::move on the result of function to construct a new object?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

can someone please confirm whether the string that comes out of that function will in fact be moved into the member var or not?

```
class Foo {
private:
  const std::string m_complex_str;

  std::string create_complex_str() {
    return std::string("some huge string");
  }

public:
  Foo() : m_complex_str(std::move(create_complex_str())) { }
};
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Maybe most compilers will do this for me without the move function?

Comment: Yeah, it will move it automatically, the `move` is unnecessary.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Even if there is no std::string() around "some huge string"?

Comment: Yes, because `create_complex_str` returns by value and that value is an xvalue at the point you construct `m_complex_str` with it. Also, having the `move` there might _prevent_ a compiler optimisation called RVO, so the `move` is not only unnecessary but harmful.

Comment: You might want to make `create_complex_str` a static member function.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: `create_complex_str()` is a prvalue and `std::move(create_complex_str())` is an xvalue.  But both allow the move constructor.

Comment: @aschepler yes, that's exactly what I said.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Why don't you put your comments into an answer? The only answer given so far is about optimization in general, but your comments give the precise and correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will be moved correctly, as the `std::string` constructor supports `std::move`, the return value of `create_complex_str()` is a pure rvalue which can be safely `move`'d. In fact, `std::move` will automatically be called even if you don't do it yourself (put a break point and see) - unless even further optimizations can be performed. But if you call `std::move` yourself, you might stop the compiler from further optimizing via copy elision/RVO, etc.

[The compiler will eliminate unnecessary copies](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) for you, where applicable. Just write your code (don't fall victim to early optimization!) to do what you want it to do in a way that makes it clear to the compiler what *logical* outcome your code should have, and let it worry about the optimization. Cases like this have been heavily studied, documented, and optimized for by all compilers.

If and when in the future you need more-performant code, you should first profile and find exactly where the bottleneck is (it's usually *not* where you think it might be), and then and only then set about using hackery to get it to work faster/better.

Comment: Well, while providing useful information in general, it totally misses the point of the question.